# How to create encrypted string with maximum 12 character from another long string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have to create the bar code for retrieve the data back. Actual string maximum size is 60. But bar code i need to print is maximum 12 characters.

Can i encrypt long string to short and decrypt again to use in c# or javascript?

Comment: I think you are looking for compression than encryption.

Comment: Have you considered creating a lookup table with keys < 12 characters as your barcode values and then finding the actual 60-character string in your table? I'm not familiar with compression algorithms otherwise -- that seems like quite a bit to go from 60 to no more than 12 characters.

Comment: @ohiodoug, Thanks for your suggestion. Creating table is not an option in current situation :-(.

Comment: Faced this problem before, and tested different compressing algorythms for numbers, but in fact you cannot get another number from source number, shorter than approx. about 65% of source length without losing information. Maybe you can use QR-codes instead of EAN-13 barcodes?

Comment: How  many characters in your source character set? How many in the barcode character set? Can we assume you won't need (sizeof charset)^60 different strings? Try a webservice-accessible database with serialized keys.

Answer (score 0):

If your text only has ASCII characters, then you might be able to reduce it by half, by actually storing multiple ASCII characters in a single UTF8 character.

This would be the actual code:

```
public static class ByteExtensions
{
    private const int BYTE_SIZE = 8;

    public static byte[] Encode(this byte[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length == 0) return new byte[0];
        int length = 3 * BYTE_SIZE;
        BitArray source = new BitArray(data);
        BitArray encoded = new BitArray(length);

        int sourceBit = 0;
        for (int i = (length / BYTE_SIZE); i > 1; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 6; j > 0; j--) encoded[i * BYTE_SIZE - 2 - j] = source[sourceBit++];
            encoded[i * BYTE_SIZE - 1] = true;
            encoded[i * BYTE_SIZE - 2] = false;
        }

        for (int i = BYTE_SIZE - 1; i > BYTE_SIZE - 1 - (length / BYTE_SIZE); i--) encoded[i] = true;
        encoded[BYTE_SIZE - 1 - (length / BYTE_SIZE)] = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= BYTE_SIZE - 2 - (length / BYTE_SIZE); i++) encoded[i] = source[sourceBit++];

        byte[] result = new byte[length / BYTE_SIZE];
        encoded.CopyTo(result, 0);
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] Decode(this byte[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length == 0) return new byte[0];
        int length = 2 * BYTE_SIZE;
        BitArray source = new BitArray(data);
        BitArray decoded = new BitArray(length);

        int currentBit = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i > 1; i--) for (int j = 6; j > 0; j--) decoded[currentBit++] = source[i * BYTE_SIZE - 2 - j];
        for (int i = 0; i <= BYTE_SIZE - 5; i++) decoded[currentBit++] = source[i];

        byte[] result = new byte[length / BYTE_SIZE];
        decoded.CopyTo(result, 0);
        return result;
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Encode(this string text)
    {
        byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        List<byte> encoded = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ascii.Length; i += 2) encoded.AddRange(new byte[] { ascii[i], (i + 1) < ascii.Length ? ascii[i + 1] : (byte)30 }.Encode());
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded.ToArray());
    }

    public static string Decode(this string text)
    {
        byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        List<byte> decoded = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < utf8.Length - 2; i += 3) decoded.AddRange(new byte[] { utf8[i], utf8[i + 1], utf8[i + 2] }.Decode());
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded.ToArray());
    }
}
```

An example:

```
string text = "This is some large text which will be reduced by half!";
string encoded = text.Encode();
```

You won't be able to render it on a console window, since the text is now UTF8, but here is what `encoded` holds: `桔獩椠⁳潳敭氠牡敧琠硥⁴桷捩⁨楷汬戠⁥敲畤散⁤祢栠污Ⅶ`

As you can see, we managed to encode a `54` characters long string into one with just `27` characters.

You can actually get back the original string by doing:

```
string decoded = encoded.Decode();
```